# Where to store two values for further comparing?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

After click over row in DataGridView I take value of two cells in this row:

```
string id = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Number"].Value);
    string type = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn46"].Value);
```

So, in which structure to store these values, that to take off them further?

In result I need to compare if `id, type` are exist in structure.

I tried `Dictionary<int, int>`. But it is hard to check if there values are in Dictionary like this: `Dictionary<'id', 'type'>`

Comment: May be Dictionary is right way, then I should use `if (dict.ContainsKey(key) && dict.ContainsValue(value)) { ... }`?

Comment: `Tuple` or `ValueTuple` is your friend.

Comment: Can it be as Tuple of array <int, int>[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>` would probably do:

1. `HashSet<T>` is a set of values which provides `O(1)` average lookup time for "contains" queries.
2. `Tuple<T1, T2>` is a class representing a pair of values, which uses value-type equality semantics, i.e. implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode` using the values stored inside the class, meaning that two different instances with same members will be considered equal (and this is important if you want to use them as `HashSet<T>` keys.

So, you would simply do something like:

```
// somewhere in your method or class
HashSet<Tuple<string, string>> hashset = new HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>();

// once you get the (id, type) pair:
hashset.Add(Tuple.Create(id, key));

// to check if the items are in the hashset:
if (hashset.Contains(Tuple.Create("a", "b")) 
{
     // do stuff
}

// to remove the item from the hashset
hashset.Remove(Tuple.Create("a", "b"));
```

Comment: And how to check if key, value are in Tuple? Tuple can content the same pairs? or when only one value the same? For example (1,2) and (1,3)?

Comment: @OPV: a `Tuple<T1, T2>` is a set of two values of any two types. The method described above allows you to check if particular set of values `(x, y)` already exists inside the set. If you need to check if any of the values exist, you would not need a `Tuple<T1, T2>` and would simply use a `HashSet<string>`. On the other hand, if you need to check `id` and `key` values separately, you would have two separate `HashSet<string>` instances.

Comment: Can I add at first: `a,b`, then `a,c`?

Comment: @OPV: `(a, b)` is completely different from `(a, c)`, as far as `HashSet<Tuple<string, string>>` is concerned.

Comment: It's a set of tuples, so you always need to create a tuple first: `var tuple = Tuple.Create("a", "b");` and then `hashset.Remove(tuple);`. `HashSet<T>` is a set of distinct items, and `Tuple<T1, T2>` is a *single item*.

Comment: Thank you, I want to accept your answer, but I need also to loop Tuple. Can I use foreach?

Comment: @OPV: yes, you can loop through the `Hashset`, check the [examples section on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples). You would again use `foreach (var tuple in hashset) { ... }`.